# Creating a prototype on string and the usage of 'this'

Tags: javascript

I am playing around with prototypes and making a prototype on String that will add dashes between each character.  The following works but the example below that was my original solution and I have no idea why it works:

Correct:

```
String.prototype.addDashes = function() {
    let word = this.split("").join("-");
    return word.toString();

}
```

My original solution....this just returns the original string but I can't tell why this would result in just the original string being returned:

```
   String.prototype.addDashes = function() {
       let word = this;
       word = this.split("").join("-");
      return word.toString();

  }
  // "test".addDashes() results in "test"
```

Comment: Both are working fine for me. Can you also show how are you using them?

Comment: `"test".addDashes()`   results in `"test"` with the 2nd approach in console

Comment: @ddjk  Sorry, my 2nd approach was copied incorrectly.  I am editing now.

Comment: `join` already returns a string. There’s no point in calling `toString` on its result. Other than that, both are working fine, currently.